# Calling super method in sails.js controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, sails.js

When I create a controller in sails.js with some standard method redefined, how do I call default parent method of this controller?

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res) {
        //test some parameters   
        if (condition) {
            //call regular super method, proceed as usual
            //_super(); <- how to do this?
        } else {
            //do some other things
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Where would this default parent method exist? Doesn't seem like you're overriding anything here, just defining a `create` controller route.

Comment: Sails.js provide its own implementation for create method in controllers. If we don't define it, it works as usual – just builds the model and saves it into the DB. The question is how to call this default implementation.

Comment: Like Mike said, you can try calling next() (the third argument to your controller action). It doesn't work for me (v0.9.3), but for newer versions it can work.

My solution is duplicating default behaviour. Since it's just couple of lines, it doesn't make a big problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Update:** for Sails >= v0.10.x, see [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110262/calling-super-method-in-sails-js-controller/18113698?noredirect=1#comment42395283_18113698) from @naor-biton

If you want to access the default implementation (the blueprint), as of v0.9.3, you can call `next()` (the third argument to your controller).  This is because Sails is based on the Express/Connect concept of middleware, allowing you to chain things together.

Please note that this behavior may change in a subsequent version, since `next()` is also how you call your default 404 handler (`config/404.js`) for actions which don't have a blueprint underneath them.

A better approach, if you're interested in using the blueprints but running a bit of logic beforehand, is to leave the controller action undefined and use one or more policies, which will be run beforehand.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll check out the policies.
Why don't you mention about using next() in controllers documentation?

Comment: By the way, it doesn't work as expected. When I use an empty controller, POST request successfully creates a model. But when I use something like this, nothing happens and empty response is returned.

`module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res, next) {
        next();
    }
};`

Comment: So this no longer works in sails .10, so are policies really the best way to handle this?

Comment: What about requiring the default blueprints and calling them?

`var create = require('sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/create');`

...

`create: function (req, res) {

  /* Do some stuff... */
  create(req, res);
}`

Comment: @NaorBiton Thanks for that idea, you saved me.

Comment: Is there a new update to this answer? None of the answer are working for me.